# Instead of text being split, pwd duplicates text

Tags: bash, macos, shell, macos-sierra

```
    echo Would you like to upgrade to osu!lazer version number: $x3
    read -r -p "Type [Y/N] to confirm decision: " response
    case "$response" in [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])\
    clear
    rm -f ~/Documents/lazerversion.txt 
    echo $x3 >> ~/Documents/lazerversion.txt 
    echo osu!lazer Updater
    echo -----------------
    echo Updating.
    x4=$(sed -n '/browser_download_url/p' ~/Documents/releasefull.txt | head -2)
    echo $x4 >> ~/Documents/tempresult.txt
    fold -s -w80 ~/Documents/tempresult.txt
    ;;
*)
    clear
    echo osu!lazer Updater
    echo -----------------
    echo Goodbye.
    ;;
esac
```

The problem is `fold -s -w80 ~/Documents/tempresult.txt`

```
"browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/install.exe" "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/osu.app.zip"
"browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/install.exe" "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/osu.app.zip"
"browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/install.exe" "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/osu.app.zip"
"browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/install.exe" "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/osu.app.zip"
"browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/install.exe" "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/osu.app.zip"
"browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/install.exe" "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/osu.app.zip"
"browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/install.exe" "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/osu.app.zip"
"browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/install.exe" "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/osu.app.zip"
"browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/install.exe" "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/osu.app.zip"
"browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/install.exe" "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/osu.app.zip"
```

I get the text above.

I want to get this:

```
"browser_download_url":
"https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/install.exe" 
"browser_download_url":
"https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/osu.app.zip"
```

The text above are in their own separate lines.

Is there anything wrong with the way I use `fold -s -w80 ~/Documents/tempresult.txt`

The original text I wanted to split into individual lines was;

```
"browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/install.exe" "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases/download/2018.915.0/osu.app.zip"
```

Thanks in advance,
Rythmic

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your data looks like JSON, and there are simple, elegant and robust tools for handling that.  I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here enough to suggest it an an answer, but for example to list all the `browser_download_url`s from GitHub assets for `ppy/osu`, you can simply do `curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/ppy/osu/releases/latest' | jq -r '.assets[].browser_download_url'` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following once.

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\n"  Input_file
```

OR

```
your_fold_command | awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\n"
```